# How to control the size of the Windows shell window from within a python script?

Tags: python, windows-shell, pywin32

When launching a script-type python file from Windows you get a windows shell type window where the script runs. How can the script determine and also set/control the Window Size, Screen Buffer Size and Window Position of said window?. I suspect this can be done with the pywin32 module but I can't find how.

Comment: It's not clear whether you asked for the window position _on the desktop_ (that's what I'm looking for) or the window position with regard to the `ScreenBuffer` (what can be done using the `SetConsoleWindowInfo` function given below).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using the [SetConsoleWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125(VS.85).aspx) function from the win32 API.  The following should work:

```
from ctypes import windll, byref
from ctypes.wintypes import SMALL_RECT

STDOUT = -11

hdl = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STDOUT)
rect = wintypes.SMALL_RECT(0, 50, 50, 80) # (left, top, right, bottom)
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleWindowInfo(hdl, True, byref(rect))
```

UPDATE:

The window position is basically what the `rect` variable above sets through the `left, top, right, bottom` arguments.  The actual size is derived from these arguments:

```
width = right - left + 1
height = bottom - top + 1
```

To set the screen buffer size to, say, 100 rows by 80 columns, you can use the [SetConsoleScreenBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686044(VS.85).aspx) API:

```
bufsize = wintypes._COORD(100, 80) # rows, columns
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(h, bufsize)
```

Comment: This works for setting Window Size. Can you also provide code for the Screen Buffer Size and Window Position. My knowledge on ctypes and the win32 API is zero.

Comment: Should STDOUT not actually be -11? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683231(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @user136036 thank you for pointing that out and providing the reference; fixed now.

Comment: I think you need to add something like `import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes` for the `rect = wintypes.SMALL_RECT(0, 50, 50, 80)` to work...