# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'window'

Tags: python, attributes, tkinter

Alright, I've seen quite a few posts concerning mostly related issues, but none were a complete match for mine.

These are the specs of the software:
Python 3.3 (multiple copies, one on Windows XP 32 bit, the other on Windows 7 64 bit)
Same issue on both copies
win32 API for Python is present on both machines

This is the code:

```
#Training Program for Chemence Owned Laser Cutter
#Written by Jared Lunt in the Python Programming Language.

try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError ("The tkinter Module is required to run this program.")

main = tkinter.Tk()

#The first objective of the app design is to state the Title
main.title("Laser Cutter Operations Training")

#The second objective of the app design is to define the size of the Main Window.
import sys, cmd
sys.path.append('C:/Python33//Lib/site-packages/win32')
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

systemWidth = GetSystemMetrics (0)
systemHeight = GetSystemMetrics (1)
width = systemWidth / 2
height = systemHeight / 2
left = width / 2
top = height / 2

window = cmd.window()
cmd.ShowWindow(window)
cmd.window(window, edit=True, topLeftCorner=( top, left ), widthHeight=( width, height ) )

main.mainloop()'
```

Comment: Also, if anyone knows of a better way to perform this code's intended function, I'm all ears.

Comment: What makes you think the [Python library `cmd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) has a `window` attribute?

Comment: Truth be told, this is simply copied from someone else in a tutorial.  the code originally called for "cmds," but I had to change it to "cmd" to fix an error I was getting.

Comment: Then *fix that error* by actually addressing the error! You are importing the wrong module here.

Comment: Like I said, if you have another way to define a window size, I sincerely would love to know about it.  I've tried other methods, and this one has given me the most progress.

Comment: Perhaps make that the focus of your question instead? Include links to that tutorial and anything else you tried.

Comment: Will do.  While I compose the list, would you know which module I should load?

Comment: Nope, sorry, no idea.

Comment: http://blog.nikosgatos.com/2011/05/07/python-controlling-window-size-and-position/ is where I got the code I'm using now.

Comment: That is *totally unrelated* to what you are trying to do. That refers to Maya (the 3D modelling package), not to TkInter. You are just stabbing in the dark here, aren't you?

Comment: Oh, ok.  I'll say yes and no to your question, since I have done coding before, but in C++ and not with a GUI in mind.

I've also tried to use the tutorial on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646362/how-to-control-the-size-of-the-windows-shell-window-from-within-a-python-script
but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting something very strange here. I wonder where you got the idea to import cmds or cmd, but any way it's not the way to go.

You can just use Tkinter's [geometry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) method to control the size and position of the window:

```
main.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (width, height, left, top) )
```

Instead of the lines using `cmd`.

Comment: Also, use `main.winfo_screenwidth()` and `main.winfo_screenheight()` instead of the Win32 system function.