# Python 2.7 lost scroll bar after using os.system("mode con: cols=80 lines=45")

Tags: python, console, resize, window

As the title suggests, I used os.system("mode con: cols=80 lines=45") to change the size of the console window, but then I lose the privilege of a scroll bar, meaning if I print out out more than  45 lines at once, I cannot scroll back up to the top. Is there a way of re-sizing the window without losing the privilege of a scroll bar?

I should also mention that I am on Windows 8

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I should have mentioned that, sorry. I'm using windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `mode con` always sets the console buffer size to be the same as the number of lines specified, which is why you're not seeing the scrollbar. You might have more luck taking a lower level approach as detailed here:

[How to control the size of the Windows shell window from within a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646362/how-to-control-the-size-of-the-windows-shell-window-from-within-a-python-script)