# How to set Python console opening position?

Tags: python, import, terminal, console, move

How to set the position of the Python console? For example:

```
os.system('mode con: cols=88 lines=30')
```

However, I want to move the window to another location. For example:

```
os.system('mode move: x=88 y=30')
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux, or some other operating system?

Comment: on Windows @Keozon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the size of the Windows shell window from within a python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646362/how-to-control-the-size-of-the-windows-shell-window-from-within-a-python-script)

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate because the 'window position' in the answer to that question refers to the _content_ of the window (the `ScreenBuffer` the window may scroll over even in horizontal direction), while the window position in this question may refer to the _desktop_ (at least, there is no content _on opening_ of the console).